#  Micromax 3G mobile internet modem not being detected

Tags: 12.04, internet, usb-modem

I have Micromax 3G modem, and I inserted it in the USB port, but it is not being detected by Ubuntu 12.04, that I'm using from a Live USB. I tried creating a mobile Internet connection, however, eventhough I created it, there is no option to connect.

I had previously used 11.10 Ubuntu, and it had automatically detected the datastick modem and asked me to create a connection.

On typing `lsusb` in the terminal it gives the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:5307 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1c9e:9605 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 5986:0364 Acer, Inc
```

tried to insert the modem before boot, with negative results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we have the same vendor & product ID, create your config same as what i have:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e:9605
```

Paste this code on the editor

```
DefaultVendor = 0x1c9e
DefaultProduct = 0x9605
TargetVendor = 0x1c9e
TargetProduct = 0x9605
MessageContent="55534243123456788000000080000606f50402527000000000000000000000"
```

Save and exit, then log in as root to your terminal:

```
su
```

Type & confirm your root password, and do:

```
modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605

usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e\:9605
```

If you didn't receive any error messages, you'll then see a new Mobile Broadband Connection on your Network Manager (top right wifi icon)

you need to run this code every session but you can just add the code below to your `/etc/rc.local` (insert before the 'exit 0') so it will be part of your startup programs:

```
 sleep 10
 modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605
 usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e\:9605
 sleep 20
 nmcli nm wwan on
 sleep 10
 nmcli con up id "your connection name here"
```

Hope this helps ..

Answer (score 0):

Followed the steps in the below mentioned link to configure the micromax 3G modem under the Ubuntu 12.04/12.10/13.04

http://imacify.com/2012/10/how-to-configure-micromax-3g-modem-on-ubuntu-12-10/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.