# Micromax USB Modem Model MMX 352G not recognized in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: usb-modem

It recognizes my modem as a mass storage device. Can someone provide me step by step instruction on how to get it working?

Browsed through some similar questions, none of the answers made sense, but seems like output of lsusb is important, so here goes

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1c9e:f000  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 064e:f203 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: [Micromax 3G mobile internet modem not being detected](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141452/144077#144077)

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you to upgrade to 12.04. Ubuntu 10.04 is very old and without any support.12.04 is also LTS

However try the following in 10.04

Don't use memory card in the slot of modem if any.

1. open synaptic package manager and download these two libraries.

   - usb-modeswitch
   - usb-modeswitch-data
2. Press ALT+ F2 and type `gconf-editor`
3. Disable auto mount :
   Click on `apps` folder in left and then navigate to `nautilus`, double click on `preferences` directory.

   on right hand side panel,uncheck the following options:

   - media_automount
   - media_automount_open

   Check this option

   - media_autorun_never
4. Reboot system. You can keep usb stick connected.

Now that you have everything setup, you can create configuration for this USB modem in network connections.