# USB internet dongle not working

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Micromax 3G mobile internet modem not being detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141452/micromax-3g-mobile-internet-modem-not-being-detected)

I am using Micromax USB dongle, it works well in Windows 7 and also worked well in Ubuntu 10.10.  When I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, it is not working in it. It does not show anything. When I start Ubuntu it shows network disabled.

If anyone has the solution kindly help.

Comment: This answer may help http://askubuntu.com/a/144077/71679

Answer (score 0):

Give a right click at your network applet in your unity top panel and there select Enable network option to enable network . If its already then check weather you have a created a connection or not for your modem .

If you have not created any connection then , select network applet and select edit connection . Choose Mobile broadband and select create new . Then Country , service provider and apn all are familiar steps with you i hope .