# Mobile internet modem still not being detected

Tags: networking

I tried to implement the answer in  [Micromax 3G mobile internet modem not being detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141452/micromax-3g-mobile-internet-modem-not-being-detected).

Here is the output of `lsusb`.

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1c9e:9913 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:d20c Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0489:e03c Foxconn / Hon Hai
```

With this information, I followed the answer step-by-step, replacing `9605` in the answer by `9913`.

`usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e\:9913`

outputs

```
Looking for target devices ...
   found matching product ID
   adding device
 Found devices in target mode or class (1)
Looking for default devices ...
   found matching product ID
   adding device
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Accessing device 004 on bus 001 ...
Getting the current device configuration ...
 OK, got current device configuration (1)
Using first interface: 0x00
Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)
Inquiring device details; driver will be detached ...
Looking for active driver ...
 OK, driver found ("usbserial_generic")
 OK, driver "usbserial_generic" detached

SCSI inquiry data (for identification)
-------------------------
  Vendor String: 
   Model String:
Revision String: Pp�
-------------------------

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Icera
     Product: USB MODEM
  Serial No.: 0.0.1
-------------------------
Setting up communication with interface 0
Using endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Resetting response endpoint 0x81
Resetting message endpoint 0x01
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.
```

I still do not have my modem detected by Ubuntu 12.04. My laptop is an Aspire 4752ZG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally forgot about this question. It seems that in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10, the default `Network Connections` is enough to fix the connection. Wait for the `Modem` icon to pop up in the Unity bar after plugging the mobile broadband stick. Right click on the icon and click on `Eject modem`. It will re-mount itself so right click on the icon again and click `Eject modem` once more. Wait for a short while and the Network icon should start showing your modem (usually follows `New Mobile Broadband`). Click on that and follow through with the installation as described, for instance, in this external site: http://daksh21ubuntu.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-establish-mobile-broadband.html